# Code for a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
Is there a way to write the condition `if ( "no draggables have been dropped in these droppables" )`? I know maybe it's possible with jQuery; and I guess it could look something like this:

`if ( $('.droppable').something( $('.draggable') ); )`

but I really don't know what exact code to use. Is there an existing method in the jQuery library, or do i need to create a new function to manually check if any draggables have been dropped?

---

**EDIT**
Apologies for such a curt question; I just needed some quick coding knowledge as I needed to finish the project fast, so I posted a question that was quickly answerable.

The question has been answered, but since it's but put on hold as 'unclear', I've decided to add some project specifics to see if other people have any other suggestions with how the droppables are being handled right now.

---

**PROJECT SPECS**
I was trying to get my droppables to display "WRONG" feedback `.css('border', '1px solid red')` when users press the `submit` button without dropping any draggables in them. I stored the information in a variable `checkwrong = 'false'` as a default, so if any draggables were NOT dropped in droppables that were WRONG, `checkwrong` would be set to `'false'`, and would return "CORRECT" feedback.

But the problem was, every time users pressed the submit button without dropping any draggables, the droppables would always display feedback for "CORRECT" `.css('border', '1px solid lime')` because there was no code that changed the value for `checkwrong` if no draggables were dropped.

**SOLUTION**
I created a block of code that runs when the submit button is clicked:

```
if (!$('.checkBox').hasClass('dropped')) {
    checkwrong1 = "true";
    checkwrong2 = "true";
    checkwrong3 = "true";
    checkwrong4 = "true";
    checkwrong5 = "true";
}
```

`.checkBox` is the universal class of all my droppables, and I set the code `$('.checkBox').addClass('dropped');` to run on the `drop:` event of every droppable.

This is a snippet of the block of code that runs whenever a draggable is dropped into a droppable.

`#dropAreaCheck1` is the unique ID of the droppable,
`#cMark1, #cMark2, etc.` are the unique IDs of the draggables.

```
$( "#dropAreaCheck1" ).droppable({

                    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
                    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
                    cursor: "arrow",
                    drop: function( event, ui) {
                        console.log(ui.draggable.attr('id')) ;
                        checkwrong1="true";
                        checkanswers ++;
                        if (checkanswers == 3) { $('.checkBox').droppable({ disabled: true }); };
                        $('.checkBox').addClass('dropped');
                        $('#dropAreaCheck1').droppable( 'disable' );

                        if(ui.draggable.attr('id') == "cMark1"){ $( "#cMark1" ).draggable({ disabled: true }); }
                        if(ui.draggable.attr('id') == "cMark2"){ $( "#cMark2" ).draggable({ disabled: true }); }
                        if(ui.draggable.attr('id') == "cMark3"){ $( "#cMark3" ).draggable({ disabled: true }); }
                        if(ui.draggable.attr('id') == "cMark4"){ $( "#cMark4" ).draggable({ disabled: true }); }
                        if(ui.draggable.attr('id') == "cMark5"){ $( "#cMark5" ).draggable({ disabled: true }); }
                        if(ui.draggable.attr('id') == "cMark6"){ $( "#cMark6" ).draggable({ disabled: true }); }
                        if(ui.draggable.attr('id') == "cMark7"){ $( "#cMark7" ).draggable({ disabled: true }); }
                        if(ui.draggable.attr('id') == "cMark8"){ $( "#cMark8" ).draggable({ disabled: true }); }                
                                $( ".drag" ).css( 'cursor', 'default' );
                                $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ disabled: false });
                                $( "#dropAreaCheck1" ).append(ui.draggable.css('position','static'))
                                $( ".drag" ).append(ui.draggable.css('margin','5px 0'))
                                $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drop something, you execute some code. Use this code and its resultant state to determine if something has been dropped or not.

For example, start with `<div class="droppable undropped">`, and on drop do `$('.droppable').removeClass('undropped')`. Then you can select by `$('.droppable.undropped')` for the "pristine" ones.

Or if the code puts something into the droppable, you can select for its contents (or absence thereof).

I can't answer this more specifically than this without knowing how exactly you handle the droppable on drop.

Comment: Actually sir, thank you, this information helped me a lot; if you'd like to know what I'm doing, I'm just checking if the users dropped anything into the droppables so I can change a variable `wrong` into `true` so everything linked to that variable is marked with a red border.